# How can I get the property value enum?

Tags: swift, enums

I have an Enum with 2 cases and each take a String and an Int as properties:

```
 public enum TestEnum {
     case case1(String, Int? = nil)
     case case2(String, Int? = nil)
 }
```

I create an enum with value case1 and these 2 properties:

```
let e = TestEnum.case1("abc", 123)
```

my question is how can I get

I tried

```
        let a = e.case1.0 // expect to get 'abc' back
        let b = e.case1.1 // expect to get '123' back
        
        print ("\(a)")
        print ("\(b)")
```

But I get compile error 'Enum case 'case1' cannot be used as an instance member'

Comment: The solutions are already written below. What I want to say is that enum's associated values are not tuples. Thus you can not access like tuples. In your case `e` is already equal to `.case1` with its associated values. `e.case1` will gave an error since `e` itself is case1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the variables is `TestEnum` for both `a` and `b`. Which exact case the variable represents isn't encoded in the type. Because of this, you cannot access associated values of an enum case variable.

Instead, you need to use if case let to conditionally cast the enum case and assign its associated values to variables.

```
let a = TestEnum.case1("a", 1)
if case let .case1(string, int) = a {
    print(string, int)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern matching to access the values. (see [patterns](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html) documentation)

Using **switch**:

```
switch e {
case .case1(let stringValue, let intValue):
    print("stringValue: \(stringValue), intValue: \(intValue)")
default:
    break
}
```

or **if**:

```
if case .case1(let stringValue, let intValue) = e {
    print("stringValue: \(stringValue), intValue: \(intValue)")
}
```